# Share music on messenger

Tags: android

Hi i made aplication(soundboard)
I have the buton when i click(OnClick) is plays music, when i hold button(longClick) is opens ContextMenu. In ContextMenu i have button. Now i need add the action for this button(button in ContextMenu) "share this music on messneger". Can help me someone?

Java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    Button contextMenuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.smiech);
    registerForContextMenu(contextMenuButton);

final MediaPlayer smiech = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.smiech);
Button playsmiech = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.smiech);
    playsmiech.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            smiech.start();
        }
    });


 @Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.item_option1:
            break;
        case R.id.item_option2:
            break;
        case R.id.item_option3:
            break;
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: We'll probably need a little more information to help you. What messenger are you talking about? If it's a specific application you're looking for, you can query the OS to see if the application is installed, and offer that as an option to the user. If it's just text messaging, you can broadcast to the OS that you want to send a text message, and the OS will respond with the apps that can handle that intent.

Comment: i thought about "Messenger" it's facebook app.